# vector emplace_back confusion

Tags: c++, c++11

I am curios about the output of this code snippet.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct base
{
  static int id;
  base() {std::cout << "C" << std::endl; mid = id; id++;}
  //base(const base&) {std::cout << "Co" << std::endl;}
  //base(base &&) {std::cout << "Mo" << std::endl;}
  ~base() {std::cout << "D" << mid << std::endl;}
  int mid;
};

int base::id = 0;

int main()
{
  std::vector<base> v;
  v.emplace_back();
  std::cout << "First" << std::endl;
  v.emplace_back();
  std::cout << "Second" << std::endl;
}
```

g++ 4.7.2 shows the output

```
C
First
C
D0
Second
D0
D1
```

I don't understand the reason why "D0" is seen after the second "C". Also, why is "D0" seen twice in the output?

Is this behavior as per the C++11 standard or is it a "quality of implementation" related aspect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `vector` is resizing as you add objects. `reserve` enough space at the beginning and you'll see the output you expect.

```
std::vector<base> v;
v.reserve(2);        // now there's enough capacity to contain at least 2 objects
v.emplace_back();
std::cout << "First" << std::endl;
v.emplace_back();
std::cout << "Second" << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
C
First
C
Second
D0
D1
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e34b8c3fb3ff2bd7)